# Seeing if I am Logged in on a different site PHP

Tags: php, mysql

On Domain.com I have a user handler that creates a session to tell him I am logged in.

So on each page I simply just do:

```
<?php 
require("http://www.domain.com/handlers/user_handler.php");
if ($user_data['loggedIn'] == 1){
echo "You are logged in!";};
?>
```

You can see if I am logged in I get a nice message that says you are logged in.

However I am wondering what it will take to tell on a different site if I am logged into the first site.

So for instance on Domain2.com. If I am logged into Domain.com can I have a message that displays You are logged into domain.com on domain2.com.

I know I wouldn;t just use the same code from above on the new domain but what is the best way to check if that session still going on from the main domain.com.

Let me know if I haven't clarified enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a different script called, say, `user_logged_in.php`, which would take a user ID as parameter and would output `1` if that user is logged in or `0` otherwise. Then you can call that script from any domain.

Just make sure the call is secure. Maybe also include a key that must have a certain value in order for the script to respond, or check the IP of the caller to be that of domain2.com.

For example, you could access the script at a URL like:

```
http://www.domain.com/handlers/user_logged_in.php?id=48&key=SECRET_KEY
```

Then you would check in `user_logged_in.php` if `$_REQUEST['key']` is indeed equal to `SECRET_KEY` (make that a little more secure though) and, if so, check the database to see if the user with id `48` is logged in or not.

Comment: Unless you host both domains, and you can directly check via a database of sessions or db entries.. but other than that, you need co-operation from the remote domain as a rule.

Comment: So I would have to let outside domains remote into my databases in order do to do that checking if there was a session?

Comment: No, you wouldn't have to give anyone access to your database. It's just that whatever script domain2 runs to figure out if the user is logged in or not could conceivably be run by anyone with the url. Thus, it would be good to add a security key, so that the script will only give out information to people with the right security key.

Answer (score 0):

Your script on Domain.com could look something like (pretend it's called login_check.php):

```
<?php
require("http://www.domain.com/handlers/user_handler.php");
if ($user_data['loggedIn'] == 1) echo "true";
else echo "false";
?>
```

Then, on Domain2.com, you would have a second script:

```
<?php
$loggedIn = file_get_contents("domain.com/login_check.php");
if ($loggedIn == "true") {
    // the user is logged in on Domain.com
} else {
    // the user is not logged in
}
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And yes, as Radu mentioned, you would probably want to make this a little more secure! As it is now, anyone could access the script on domain.com and could figure out if a user was logged in or not.

Comment: Hey Ord. I can't get the second part of the script to work. I'm getting the true to come up on the first domain however I can't get the second domain to read that it is true.

Comment: Okay ... is the second script running without problems? If so, try echoing the value of $loggedIn, to see if it is what you expect it to be. If you are using a free hosting service, the host might be appending something to the end of everything your scripts return. If this is the case, you will need to just compare the first four characters.

Comment: I did try echoing the value $loggedIn and it is returning false even though my main domain is returning true. I am not using Free hosting.

Comment: How do you know your main domain is returning true if the value you are getting back is false?

Comment: My main domain is returning true because I can load domain.com/login_check.php it says true. On domain_2.com it is returning false.

Comment: Hmmmm... what script are you using to determine whether or not the user is logged in? The second script I gave you literally just runs the first and returns the result as a string. So I think the problem is that whatever you are doing to determine if the user is logged in or not is returning different results depending on where it is called from.

Comment: But if I have the first script echoing True why wouldn't the second script just read that it says True? Or is that not what it is doing?

Comment: Yes, that _should_ be what it's doing ... what I'm saying is, each time you run the file_get_contents(), you run the first script again. You don't read its last output, you generate a new output. Essentially, you ask the server to give you whatever is in login_check.php, the server says: "Oh look, a PHP file! I will run it through my php interpreter before sending it off!" and the script is run. Therefore, I think the problem is that the first script is not always returning true when it should, and what it returns actually depends on where it is called from ... or something.

Comment: Ahh yeah. I think you are right. I am using login handler that is requiring another class php file. Maybe when it is getting read from an outside server it tries to run that file on my first servers and gets confused because they are not absolute urls in the handlers and class. could that be it?

Comment: Well, whatever you do in the first script is actually getting run on your domain.com servers, so relative urls shouldn't be a problem. What are you doing to tell if the user is logged in or not? If you are just storing data in a session, this might be your problem. PHP sessions work by storing a cookie on your computer with an id. This cookie is sent to the server along with every request. BUT, when you use file_get_contents(), you DON'T send a cookie. So the domain.com servers can't open the session. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yep. I start my handler that checks if the user is logged in with 

<?php session_start();

So it's because the second domain can't read the session/cookie being stored?

Comment: Could it also have to do with because my mysql_connect("localhost", is setup like that? and when it is being run on the 2nd domain obviously localhost won't work?

Comment: No, the first PHP script is still being run _on the domain.com servers_, as per usual. The only difference I can think of is that it won't have access to the cookie, and thus won't have access to the session data. To remedy this, what about storing the login data in mysql instead of in session? Then, you could do something like what Radu suggested, and submit a user id when you call the first script from domain2.com. Your domain.com script could look up the user in your mysql database, and then return whether or not the user is logged in.